# Incorrect Statement not covered / if path not taken in jest coverage report

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I'm getting a couple of 'statement not covered/if path not taken' lines in my jest coverage report. I've added in some console.log lines just to make sure that the tests definitely cover those sections. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

[image: Coverage report and jest output]

Answer (score -1):

The `if` condition lines are uncovered means your if condition is not satisfied. Try to mock a data in such a way that you will be able to satisfy your `if` condition. And when your `if` condition is satisfied your console statement also will get executed.

Comment: Both console statements ran (multiple times) during the tests, you can see the output in the console window.

Comment: How to cover the if statement inside method from vue using jest coverage?

Comment: Any advise for that line 66 half-if not covered? I have a similar right now (just booleans though) and my test data is truthy for the all the parts in the if, yet half of it is marked as not covered

Comment: @Purefan maybe you need to add a test case where that half is falsy as well